# animation with tree.js does not accept my torus

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, three.js, 3d

I am new to Three.js and cannot work out why this animation does not accept the torus as a parameter. Without setting 'torusToBeMoved' as a parameter it works just perfectly fine..

````
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(25, 0.2, 26, 100);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xccaa55 });
const torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
torus.position.set(-15, -15, -15);

scene.add(torus);

function animate(torusToBeMoved) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate(torusToBeMoved));

  torusToBeMoved.rotation.x += 0.01;
  torusToBeMoved.rotation.y += 0.005;
  torusToBeMoved.rotation.z += 0.01;
  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate(torus);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error since you are passing the return value of the function as parameter instead of passing the function as parameter. Utilizing a callback as parameter should solve the issue:

```
const animate = (torusToBeMoved) => {
  torusToBeMoved.rotation.x += 0.01;
  torusToBeMoved.rotation.y += 0.005;
  torusToBeMoved.rotation.z += 0.01;

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  requestAnimationFrame(() => animate(torusToBeMoved));
}
```